# Display massage after pjax success by clicking on specific input only

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, onchange, pjax

I have a form which submits when any change is made on any of the radio `input`'s.

Inside the form I have two different radio groups. I am trying to output a message on my `#message` on `pjax:start` when any of the radios from `group2` **only** is triggered.

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="radio" name="group1" val="ga_1_1">
    <input type="radio" name="group1" val="ga_1_2">

    <input type="radio" name="group2" val="ga_2_1">
    <input type="radio" name="group2" val="ga_2_2">
</form>

<span id="message"></span>
```

Here is my simplyfied approach:

```
$('input[name="group2"]').on('change', function(){
   $(document).on('pjax:start', function() {
     $('#message').text( 'Loading...' );
   });

   $(document).on('ready pjax:success', function() {
     $('#message').text( 'Loaded' );
   });
});
```

Problem is that the message triggers even if I click on radio `group1`.

Comment: Try this .............                                                             $('document').on('change', 'input[name="group2"]', function(){

   $(document).on('pjax:start', function() {
     $('#message').text( 'Loading...' );
   });

   $(document).on('ready pjax:success', function() {
     $('#message').text( 'Loaded' );
   });

});

Comment: thanks @ CognitiveDesire but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Event declaration should be done only once. Here, you declare event each time you click on an input that have name equal to group2.

Answer (score 5):

You've the right selector no need for change it, you could use `$.pjax` callbacks directly :

```
$('input[name="group2"]').on('change', function(){
    $.pjax({
        url: '/url',
        container: '#container',
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('#message').text( 'Loading...' );
        },
        complete: function(){
            $('#message').text( 'Loaded' );
        }
    });
});
```

Or also you could put out the callbacks and use `send & complete` instead as are the best if you're in loading purpose as described in the **[Official Documentation](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax)** :

> pjax:send & pjax:complete are a good pair of events to use if you are implementing a loading indicator

```
$(function(){
    $('input[name="group2"]').on('change', function(){
       $.pjax({url: "/url", container: '#container'})
    });

    $(document).on('pjax:send', function() {
        $('#message').text( 'Loading...' );
    })
    $(document).on('pjax:complete', function() {
        $('#message').text( 'Loaded' );
    })
})
```

**NOTE :** No need for the `ready` callback since it will init your `#message` with `Loaded` when the page is loaded before any `$.pjax` request.

Take a look to **[best way to implement an overlay with pjax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709813/best-way-to-implement-an-overlay-with-pjax)**.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="radio" class="rdgroup2" name="group2" val="ga_2_2">


 $('.rdgroup2').on('change', function(){
    //do something
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are redeclaring your events every time your inputs change. You could do it easier. I'm only using a variable to store if you clicked on your input or not.

```
//Variable that is true is you clicked on group2, false else
var shoulddisplay = false;

//On change in your input, update the variable
$('input[name="group2"]').on('change', function(){
    shoulddisplay = true; 
});


$(document).on('pjax:start', function() {
    //Display message only if you clicked on group2
    if (true === shoulddisplay) {
        $('#message').text( 'Loading...' );
    }
});

$(document).on('ready pjax:success', function() {
    //Display message only if you clicked on group2
    if (true === shoulddisplay) {
        $('#message').text( 'Loaded' );
    }
    shoulddisplay = false;
});
```